# read_excel modifies unexpected data

Tags: pandas

Is it possible that the pandas function read_excel is modifing data from the excel?

It seems it changes for example TRUE to 1 and FALSE to False.

I use this code

df = pd.read_excel(DEFAULT_PATH_2_XLSX_FILE, , dtype=str)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation to that. Pandas read the raw values of cell not the shown values:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', dtype=str, header=None)
print(df)

# Output
   0  1
0  1  0  # A1, B1
1  1  0  # A2, B2
2  1  0  # A3, B3
```

[image: raw values]

In this screenshot, this is how I entered values:

- A1: 1
- B1: 0
- A2: 1 then formatted as boolean value
- B2: 0 then formatted as boolean value
- A3: TRUE (type as it)
- B3: FALSE (type as it)